# Pass variable to PHP from JavaScript Object once it gets the Object value

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on a task where I get couple of ID's inside JavaScript Object. Once, I have the required ID's, I then need to pass it to backend server and process them accordingly. So how do I pass those object values to PHP with the restriction that my PHP code runs Only when JavaScript Object has those values. For example:

JavaScript Object:

```
Object = {
documentA{id:'azer2784r5s'},
documentB{id:'zef2457fTfz'}
}
```

I stored the values in variables, and then wrote JavaScript code inside the PHP. But it is not working and I am getting an error, as PHP runs before the JavaScript and gives an error or perhaps that is not the write way of passing data to PHP from JavaScript Object.

```
<script>
Object = {
documentA{id:'azer2784r5s'},
documentB{id:'zef2457fTfz'}
}
documentAid = (Object.documentA.id);
documentBid = (Object.documentB.id);
</script>
<?php
$documentAid = '<script>document.writeln(documentAid);</script>';
$documentBid = '<script>document.writeln(documentBid);</script>';
?>
```